# VBA function acts differenty in Excel shared workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button on a sheet that gets information from other sheets then deletes every thing on the sheet with the button from cell C1 to Cell ff112 then displays the data.

This works fine when i have the workbook in exclusive mode so noone else can edit it, but When i "Protect and share" it the button deletes all cells including row A and B AND deletes the button.

Why does this button work differently in shared mode than non shared?

ok so I have narrowed it down to this code

```
Sub Eraser()
    Sheets("Batch Record Progress").Activate
    Workbooks("Work in Process.xls").Sheets("Batch Record Progress").Range("C1:FF112").Select
    Selection.Delete
    Workbooks("Work in Process.xls").Sheets("Batch Record Progress").Range("C1").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: The code is in multiple sheets and multiple functions

Comment: I meant include them in your question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I just meant its to spread out to post but I've narrowed the problem down now

Comment: [You don't need to Select or Activate anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mat's Mugs Link I was able to solve it
I'm still not sure why it worked differently in shared but it works now so thanks

Working code below

```
Sub Eraser()
    Workbooks("Work in Process.xls").Sheets("Batch Record Progress").Range("C1:FF112").Clear
    Sheets("Batch Record Progress").Activate
    Workbooks("Work in Process.xls").Sheets("Batch Record Progress").Range("C1").Activate
End Sub
```